# Connection to a TFS server using c# console application

Tags: c#, tfs

I am developing a c# console application in which i want to connect to my TFS server and access the information from it.

My TFS server is: http://vstfpg05:8080/tfs/ESITAPP

Basically, we maintain a ticketing system through TFS and i want to access the service names of the tickets.

[image]

Above is a snip of my tfs system.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Cab someone please tell me how do i connect to my tfs instance and access workitems from it?

Comment: The content in the screenshot you provide are queries, not workitems. What do you want to get via C$ console app? Queries or workitems?

Comment: I basically want to access the field like ID and various other columns..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically connect to a server that is running Team Foundation and then access the team projects on that server if you using **Client API** with the following example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client; 
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;

namespace TfsApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // Connect to Team Foundation Server
            //     Server is the name of the server that is running the application tier for Team Foundation.
            //     Port is the port that Team Foundation uses. The default port is 8080.
            //     VDir is the virtual path to the Team Foundation application. The default path is tfs.
            Uri tfsUri = (args.Length < 1) ? 
                new Uri("http://Server:Port/VDir") : new Uri(args[0]);

            TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer =
                TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);

            // Get the catalog of team project collections
            ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(
                new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },
                false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

            // List the team project collections
            foreach (CatalogNode collectionNode in collectionNodes)
            {
                // Use the InstanceId property to get the team project collection
                Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
                TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);

                // Print the name of the team project collection
                Console.WriteLine("Collection: " + teamProjectCollection.Name);

                // Get a catalog of team projects for the collection
                ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> projectNodes = collectionNode.QueryChildren(
                    new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject },
                    false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

                // List the team projects in the collection
                foreach (CatalogNode projectNode in projectNodes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Team Project: " + projectNode.Resource.DisplayName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More detail info please refer this tutorial from MSDN: [Connect to Team Foundation Server from a Console Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958(v=vs.120).aspx)